# Display recursive content on Jinja

Tags: jinja2

I want to display in a webpage the contents of a dictionary. The dictionary structure is recursive. I can not make it work though like that. Instead, I have to "manually unfold" the recursion. Probably, I have not understood correctly the documentation.

Code without the use of recursion (and it works).

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body %}
<form action="">
{% for account in account_list['account_list'] %}
<ul>
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{ account['id'] }}" value="{{ account['name'] }}" type="{{ account['type'] }}"> {{ account['name'] }} <br>
    {% for key, value in account.items() %}
        {% if value is not string %}
            {% for acc in value %}
                {% if acc is mapping %}
                    <ul> 
                        <input type="checkbox" id="{{ acc['id'] }}" value="{{ acc['name'] }}" type="{{ acc['type'] }}"> {{ acc['name'] }} <br>
                        {% for ke, va in acc.items() %}
                            {% if va is not string %}
                                {% for ac in va %}
                                    {% if ac is mapping %}
                                        <ul>
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="{{ ac['id'] }}" value="{{ ac['name'] }}" type="{{ ac['type'] }}"> {{ ac['name'] }} <br>
                                        </ul>
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Code with recursion but it does not work.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body %}
<form action="">
{% for account in account_list['account_list'] %}
<ul>
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{ account['id'] }}" value="{{ account['name'] }}" type="{{ account['type'] }}"> {{ account['name'] }} <br>
    {% for key, value in account.items() recursive %}
        {% if value is not string %}
            {% for acc in value %}
                {% if acc is mapping %}
                    <ul> 
                        <input type="checkbox" id="{{ acc['id'] }}" value="{{ acc['name'] }}" type="{{ acc['type'] }}"> {{ acc['name'] }} <br>
                        {% loop(acc.items()) %}
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Relevant documentation: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/ (look for the recursive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `loop` always refers to the innermost (closest) loop. Here, it refers to the loop `{% for acc in value %}`. In order to refer to the outer loop, we should rebind it immediately after the `{% for key, value in account.items() recursive %}` loop, by writing something like:

```
{% set outer_loop = loop %}
```

Then, we get the desired results, by using

```
outer_loop(acc.items())
```

Answer (score 0):

You *probably* need to change `{% loop(acc.items()) %}` to simply be `{% loop(acc) %}` since the outer loop expects a mapping, not a list (and calling `.items` on a list will result in an error.)

If changing the call *does* fix the problem then I would file a bug with the Jinja2 project - this *should* have blown up with an error, rather than silently swallowing it (since `acc.items` *will* be an iterable).

Comment: ...But the `recursive` keyword has been put in a loop which expects a list of tuples.

Comment: @DimitrisLeventeas - `list` objects do not have an `items` method - this code *should* blow up immediately when passed a list of tuples.  **`dict`** instances have a `items` method (which is what I'm guessing you are passing to the template - but not what you are passing to the `loop`.

Comment: `acc` is a dict. See the check above.

Comment: @DimitrisLeventeas - Exactly - as is `account` in the recursive `for` loop - so when the loop recurses it expects that the `account` it will be provided with have an `items` method - **which a list of tuples does not**.